# Using multiple input sliders to change their own individual class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So basically the idea is to start a presentation of different fonts/typography with simple options the first one being the possibility to change the size of each font. So I tried a very non-economical logic by changing the querySelector with a class but it seems to only take the first input range slider that changes the whole body. My question is how can I make multiple input range sliders that can change specific things (here the example is size but later on I would like to add spacing, line height & width per font). So I don't know how to get around this and apply one input slider to a certain class?

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_1').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_2').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_3').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_4').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_5').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('.font_6').style.fontSize = e
  .target.value + 'em');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
    <p class="font_1">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
    <label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
    <p class="font_2">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
    <label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
    <p class="font_3">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
    <label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
    <p class="font_4">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
    <label>Change font-size</label>
    <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
    <p class="font_5">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a way to do it would be to add an identifier to each of the `p` elements. It could be a class, an id or event an attribute.
Then you can also add an attribute to each of the inputs telling them which `p` element they should affect.

I have created a little snippet for you, where i use the `class-to-change` attribute on the inputs with the corresponding class name of the `p` element they should change.

Then we loop through the inputs and when an input changes we also change the font-size of the corresponding `p` element.

Both the html and js could use a bit of cleaning up (the different inputs shouldn't have the same id, we should use a class to select the inputs, catch possible errors on the js, ...), but i think you can handle that!

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', handleInputChange);
})

function handleInputChange(event) {
  const classToChange = event.target.getAttribute('class-to-change');
  const propertyToChange = event.target.getAttribute('property-to-change');
  const targetPElement = document.querySelector(`.${classToChange}`);
  
  targetPElement.style[propertyToChange] = `${event.target.value}em`;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <label>Change font-size</label>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="fontSize"/>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="letterSpacing"/>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_1" property-to-change="lineHeight"/>
      <p class="font_1">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
      <label>Change font-size</label>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_2" property-to-change="fontSize"/>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_2" property-to-change="letterSpacing"/>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_2" property-to-change="lineHeight"/>
      <p class="font_2">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
      <label>Change font-size</label>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_3"/>
      <p class="font_3">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
      <label>Change font-size</label>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_4"/>
      <p class="font_4">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
      <label>Change font-size</label>
      <input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="font_5"/>
      <p class="font_5">Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
    </header>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This is great! Exactly what I was looking for. If it's ok I would like to follow up with a second question where I still can't wrap my head around how to write the JS. It is if each <p> has three sliders, the one that changes the size like above, one that changes spacing and the other that changes line height. How would you proceed as the input is directed to the same class?

Comment: @ambaamba You can add additional inputs for each of the properties you want to change. The you can add an attribute to the input, for instance `property-to-change`, which tells you which css property that input changes.
I have added a second input(for the letter spacing) to the first element on the example. I hope that is what you were looking for...

Comment: @ambaamba if it works, you can accept the answer as correct so it can also help other people in the future!  

Comment: Great, so I tried the code but once I add the line `property-to-change` the other sliders for size stopped working this is where I get a little confused with these input range sliders. I didn't understand how the second one affects the spacing value in the JS. Thanks in advance for taking the time!

Comment: The value that you give to the `property-to-change` attribute is the css property that the slider will change. With the `class-to-change` you define which element it will affect.
You can have as many inputs as you need for each of the targets.
Example: if you want an input to change the line-height of a target element with the class `my-class` you can and the following input `<input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" class-to-change="my-class" property-to-change="lineHeight"/>`

Comment: @ambaamba i have updated my example on the answer to add an input also for the line-height. I also added a second set of inputs for the second element. I hope this helps you...